# How to run a count in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

I have a Real Estate site with a Properties table and a PropertyImages table.
When the user uploads a picture, I want to run a query in the PropertyImages. then append that number to the picturename.

```
    public IQueryable GetPictureCount()
   {
     int propertyId = Convert.ToInt16(ddlSelectProperty.SelectedValue);
     var _db = new RESolution.Models.PropertyContext();
     IQueryable query = _db.PropertyImages;

    var mypic = (from c in _db.PropertyImages
                where c.PropertyID == propertyId
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
            lblCount.Text = Convert.ToString(query);
    }
```

I get this error: "Not all code paths return a value"

My environment is as follows:

```
VS Express 2013
Sql Express 
win 8.1 development computer
```

when I change IQuaryable to "void" I get the error

'lblCount.text = query.Count().ToString();'
System.Linq.IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'Count' I have looked for a using directive but found non

Comment: You have to invoke the query and print the result: lblCount.text = query.Count().ToString();

Comment: Since your method is called **Get**PictureCount, and because it is declared as returning `IQueryable`, there needs to be a `return` statement somewhere. If you use your method for its side effects, replace `IQueryable` with `void` to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am still a little confused, though you guys are a god send.
Here is where I was able to get to work.

public void GetPictureCount()
        {

```
        lblfnameCheck.Text = ddlSelectProperty.SelectedValue;
        int propertyId = Convert.ToInt32(lblfnameCheck.Text);
        var _db = new RESolution.Models.PropertyContext();

        var count = _db.PropertyImages.Count(t => t.PropertyID == propertyId);
        lblCount.Text = Convert.ToString(count);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As dasblinkenlight mentioned, it seems that you do not want to return something, so make the method a void.
You probable want something like this:

```
public void GetPictureCount()
{
   int propertyId = Convert.ToInt16(ddlSelectProperty.SelectedValue);
   var _db = new RESolution.Models.PropertyContext();
   IQueryable query = _db.PropertyImages;

   var mypic = (from c in _db.PropertyImages
            where c.PropertyID == propertyId
            select c).FirstOrDefault();

   var nrOfPics = Convert.ToString(query.Count());
   lblCount.Text = nrOfPics;
   mypic.name = mypic.name + nrOfPics; // I am guessing the name property

  _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: var nrOfPics = Convert.ToString(query.Count()); shows an error that IQueryable does not contain a definition 'Count' also the following has runtime error  int propertyId = Convert.ToInt16(ddlSelectProperty.SelectedValue);